# SQL- Pattern Matching no output

Tags: mysql, sql, pattern-matching

I have to print the list of names which does not start and end with vowels.
I typed in the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME 
FROM STUDENT 
WHERE NAME NOT LIKE '[AEIOU]%' 
  AND NAME NOT LIKE '%[aeiou]' 
ORDER BY NAME;
```

And it produced no results on the output screen.
What's the problem here?

Comment: Can you clarify what data you have in your database? Did you see in the [documentation:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) `To anchor a pattern so that it must match the beginning or end of the value being tested, use “^” at the beginning or “$” at the end of the pattern.`?

Comment: Data is simple as created by me for practice

Comment: using the above suggestion still gives wrong output

Comment: Consider using the "edit" button to show some example data and the new code you have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RLIKE` and regex:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/053328/2/0)**

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME 
FROM STUDENT 
WHERE NAME RLIKE '^[^aeouiy].*[^aeouiy]$' 
ORDER BY NAME;
```